# Authorize Channel in Laravel Package

Tags: laravel, broadcast, laravel-7, pusher, authorize

I am developing a laravel package where i need to authorize a private channel.

In my normal laravel project(not the package) everything is working fine:

**Event SendMessage:**

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('chat');
}
```

and in my `route/channel.php` i do as follows:

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    return Auth::check();
});
```

But how can i authorize my chat channel inside my laravel package?

In my laravel package the service provider has boot and register functions, as with `routes/web.php` i know we can register it but what to do with the channels? Can we register them? i find no documentation regarding that Please help.

I am using **pusher server and with laravel echo.**

Hopefully you can understand my question. I just wanna know how can i authroize channel in my package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my own question is that We must uncomment a line from `config/app.php` which is :

```
     App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

I was struggling with the channels and it comes to the point that , we do not need to register the channels or broadcasting services in our package.

They are by default globally enabled.

So everything remains the same and just by uncommenting that i was able to authorize the private channel.

Hoepfully it helps someone.

Cheers.

Comment: That service provider isn't aware of channels on your package (and shouldn't be)